# Adjust height to 100% width of container in firefox

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a square shaped div that side is equal to width of container. I achieve this thanks to this forum by adding pseudo-element to my div:

```
.helper::before {
    content:'';
    padding-top:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

It works on chrome but not in firefox. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Can you send us a code or picture of what you want ? I don't understand what you want

Comment: I figure out it flexbox couse the issue. If I delete display: flex then works also on firefox. In brief i want red box be always square. https://codepen.io/whomean/pen/XZjWEa

Comment: It did not helps me at all. Still don't know what you want. Why are you using a pseudo element to achieve this ?

Comment: Trick with pseudo element i took from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537806/css-height-same-as-width

Answer (score 0):

This works in Firefox, the psuedo-element needs a width. I added background colour and a height/width so you can see it working on helper.

```
.helper::before {
 content:'';
 padding-top: 100%;
 width: 5px;
 background: blue;
 float:left;
}

.helper{
 background: red;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/BenKingstown/pen/mXrbZK

Comment: Didn't work. I have fluid container, and div inside this container which need to be 100% container width and the same height.  codepen.io/whomean/pen/XZjWEa

Answer (score 0):

Is it this that you want ?

I will edit if you give me more informations ...

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50vw;
}
.square {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}
.helper {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square helper">
    dfgdf
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. I want to set height of .square dynamically so that all sides of .square div  have the same size. When I resize window it need to resize height of .square div.  codepen.io/whomean/pen/XZjWEa Run this in chrome and resize window to see what i want. Didn't work in forefox and I don't know why.